# MonoDroid Java Bindings : Control constants naming

Tags: java, binding, xamarin.android

When creating Java Bindings with MonoDroid, it converts Java Constants names containing underscores to C# camel case names:

[Register ("SOME_CONSTANT_NAME")]
public const int SomeConstantName = (int) 3;

I know this is the "common" naming convention in .NET, but I would like to keep the original names.

Is it possible to control the naming transformations, ie. to globally turn off the camel case transformation ?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Android (formerly known as MonoDroid) allows you to control aspects of the generated C# bindings using metadata transforms. The relavent documentation is here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/api_metadata_reference/

Specifically the `EnumFields.xml` file controls the transforms used when generating enums based on java int constants. Example:

```
<type enum-type="Some\Package\MyClassEnumType" java-class="some/package/MyClass$MyConstants">
   <member enum="CONSTANT_ONE" java="CONSTANT_ONE" value="1" />
   <member enum="CONSTANT_ZERO" java="CONSTANT_ZERO" value="0" />
</type>
```

Comment: but this way you have to map every single name. I have hundreds of constants and therefore it would nice if you just could turn off the naming transformation , ie. the enum member name should be same as the java constant name